# Django admin action-select checkbox removal?

Tags: django-admin

Pretty simple question. I have removed the top select-box, for choosing an action to perform on the selected models. However, the leftmost checkbox does not disappear, even though I have no action toolbar neither in top or in bottom.

This is very annoying, as it looks as if it is a field for the given model, just without any headline. See image below... Which has only two attributes - Description and CurrentSeason.

[image: annoying checkbox]

I hope someone can help me remove this checkbox!

Answer (score 13):

If you had removed the actions drop down list by settings your ModelAdmin's actions to None, the action_checkbox should've been removed as well.

```
class SeasonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = None
```

Here is the doc link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-all-actions-for-a-particular-modeladmin